# Does $a_n = 0 \mod (6n + 2)$ hold for $n_0 = 2755452$ where $a_0 = 2, a_1 = 10, a_2 = 51, a_{n+3}=a_n + 2 a_{n + 1} + 5 a_{n + 2}$?

Tags: number-theory

Define the sequence $a_n$ by the following.

> $$a_0 = 2, a_1 = 10, a_2 = 51,$$
>
> $$a_{n+3}=a_n + 2 a_{n + 1} + 5 a_{n + 2}$$

Prove that $a_n = 0 \mod (6n + 2)$ holds for $n_0 = 2755452$ and for no smaller value of n.

([http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Solution5.2.html](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/Zagier/Solution5.2.html))

Comment: Done, now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't prove the question by math.
So I calculate $ a_{n}\mod (6 n + 2) $ by programming.

Main idea is the following.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+3}\\
a_{n+2}\\
a_{n+1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+2}\\
a_{n+1}\\
a_{n}\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I compute the number by using the following code(ruby) and the number is 2755452. And no smaller value exists.

```
require 'matrix'

def power(a, n, mod)
  return Matrix.I(a.row_size) if n == 0
  m = power(a, n >> 1, mod)
  m = (m * m).map{|i| i % mod}
  return m if n & 1 == 0
  (m * a).map{|i| i % mod}
end

def f(n)
  ary0 = [51, 10, 2]
  v = Vector.elements(ary0)
  ary1 =
  [[5, 2, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0]]
  a = Matrix[*ary1]
  mod = 6 * n + 2
  (power(a, n, mod) * v)[2] % mod
end

(1..10 ** 8).each{|i|
  if f(i) == 0
    p i
    break
  end
}
```

Output (It takes about 40 minutes.)

```
2755452
```

P.S.

The second smallest number is 4570452. However, the third smallest number isn't 6385452(= 4570452 + 1815000).